# Why does TensorFlow attempt to restore a key from a checkpoint that I didn't ask for?

Tags: tensorflow

When I attempt to restore a variable from a checkpoint, TensorFlow looks for a key I didn't specify and reports an error.

I can save my variable under the expected key with

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

raw_data = [1., 2., 8., -1., 0., 5.5, 6., 13]
spikes = tf.Variable([False] * len(raw_data), name='spikes')
spikes.initializer.run()

# After variables, listing them in a dict if not all are to be saved
saver = tf.train.Saver()

for i in range(1, len(raw_data)):
    spikes_val = spikes.eval() # Get the current values
    spikes_val[i] = True # Update new value
    updater = tf.assign(spikes, spikes_val).eval() # Assign updated values to Variable

save_path = saver.save(sess, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '_save_eg.ckpt'))
print("spikes data saved in file: %s" % save_path)

sess.close()
```

and can confirm that this has been successful with

```
tf.contrib.framework.list_variables(save_path)
```

which gives

```
[('spikes', [8])]
```

as expected.

But when I attempt to read this variable with

```
sess_in = tf.InteractiveSession()

spikes_read = tf.Variable([False] * len(raw_data), name='spikes')
tf.train.Saver().restore(sess_in, save_path)
print(spikes_read)

sess_in.close()
```

I get a `NotFoundError` for a key, 'spikes_1', that I didn't ask for:

```
NotFoundError: Key spikes_1 not found in checkpoint [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_1 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_BOOL], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save_1/Const_0_0, save_1/RestoreV2_1/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_1/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Why does TensorFlow attempt to restore a key from a checkpoint that I did not ask for?

---

This is basically the example from p.44 of [Machine Learning With TensorFlow](https://www.manning.com/books/machine-learning-with-tensorflow), which fails to work as is, as does much of the code in the book.

Answer (score 0):

Your reading phase is wrong. You already have declared the `spikes` variable before, this means that a variable named `spikes` **do** exists in the current graph.

When you're trying to restore the model, you're doing this:

```
spikes_read = tf.Variable([False] * len(raw_data), name='spikes')
```

that's a new declaration of a variable called `spikes`: this variable already exists in the current graph, therefore Tensorflow adds the `_1` suffix for you in order to avoid conflicts.

At the next line:

```
tf.train.Saver().restore(sess_in, save_path)
```

you're asking the `Saver` to use the current graph for restoring the variables from the `save_path`.
Clearly, this means that the saver expects to find not only the `spikes` variable previously declared but also the new `spikes_1` variable.

You can solve your issue in two different way:

#### First way

If you look at the documentation of [`tf.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) you can see that is constructor accepts a list of variables to restore.
Hence, you can just use the previously declared variable `spikes` and pass it as the constructor argument.

So your read phase becomes:

```
sess_in = tf.InteractiveSession()

# comment the `spikes_1` variable definition and just use the
# `spikes` varialble previously declared
#spikes_read = tf.Variable([False] * len(raw_data), name='spikes')
tf.train.Saver().restore(sess_in, save_path)
# or you can explicit the variable into the saver in this way, that's
# the same exact thing
# tf.train.Saver([spikes]).restore(sess_in, save_path)
print(spikes_read)

sess_in.close()
```

#### Second way

You can wrap your read phase into a new empty graph. So you can now declare a variable which name will be `spikes` that will be filled by the saver:

```
new_graph = tf.Graph()
with new_graph.as_default():
    sess_in = tf.InteractiveSession()

    spikes_read = tf.Variable([False] * len(raw_data), name='spikes')
    tf.train.Saver().restore(sess_in, save_path)
    print(spikes_read)
```

Comment: The first way doesn't really match the general scenario, which is that in some other section of the code where I may not know whether there's a variable called `spikes` lying around, I want to read in variable from the checkpoint called "spikes". The second way produces errors (e.g. "RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run()").

Comment: Sorry. The second way must have the variable definition uncomment and it will work, I'm going to edit the code. The first scenario works, but if you want to get a variable that's already defined in the graph you have to use `tf.get_variable('spikes`) whitin a variable scope with `reuse` enabled. Have a look here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable